# Update query shows null value on a record but the formula works as calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

So I'm facing a really weird situation and I'm out of ideas.

I got a single table (with a primary key named ID_STG_DATA) with several fields and I need to update the value of one of them based on values from other fields in the same table.

This sounds easy and I've done it a million times but something strange is happening.

First of all, I created a query to test with a calculated field if everything works good. The code is:

```
SELECT T_REMESA_FINAL.ID_STG_DATA, IIf(([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]=0) Or ([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]<=[Limite_concedido]),0,DCount("[ID_STG_DATA]","T_REMESA_FINAL","[Exclusion_D]='Asegurado CESCE' AND [Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]=" & Replace(Format([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE],"#.00"),",",".") & " AND [Nominal]>=" & Replace(Format([Nominal],"#.00"),",","."))) AS test
FROM T_REMESA_FINAL
ORDER BY T_REMESA_FINAL.ID_STG_DATA;
```

This works perfectly and returns all correct values. Please, notice the value `3` in the row 87:

[image]

Now that I got the formula I need, I switch to an update query. The code is:

```
UPDATE T_REMESA_FINAL SET T_REMESA_FINAL.Rank_Asegurado_CESCE = IIf(([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]=0) Or ([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]<=[Limite_concedido]),0,
DCount("[ID_STG_DATA]","T_REMESA_FINAL","[Exclusion_D]='Asegurado CESCE' AND [Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]=" & Replace(Format([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE],"#.00"),",",".") & " AND [Nominal]>=" & Replace(Format([Nominal],"#.00"),",",".")));
```

As you can see in the code, the formula to update field `T_REMESA_FINAL.Rank_Asegurado_CESCE` is **exactly** the same as testing before and it worked.

But when executed, the row 87 gets a null value, not a 3 value and I'm totally stuck about how is this possible?

[image]

I remade everything from scratch and still happening. No events or macros involved, pure SQL code and Access expressions. I'm totally out of my mind with this.

I've uploaded a reduced sample of my db into Google Drive for easy replication and with no confidential info:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x8k33iJFisB187rRVl3LXBSilakYb6IY/view?usp=share_link

I'm pretty sure the answer is really easy or stupid but I cannot find it. I've been hours stuck on this and can't think properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you save calculated value? If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed.

Comment: SO discourages links to file downloads. Many will not download files for external location. All information to analyze issue should be included within question. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files.

Comment: However, I did download file. I ran the query and field is updated.

Comment: @ I need to save the value because querying is slower in complex calculus. I've uploaded just a clena version of database, but my database got thousands of records and many more calculated fields. I'm updating tables with them because if I executed all the queries everytime i need to check the value, calculation takes around 15 minutes every time but if I update, it takes 15 mintues just once.

Comment: @June7 O_o no null value when updating? I've downloaded the file in a different machine, test and still the same, null value on record 87.

Comment: The query works fine for me as well using O365 version, I also get sensible results without all the formatting and replacements. 
What would be far better than a DCount() in the query would be to simply join your test query to the update and use the Test field to provide the updated value. Far more efficient. Try test2: IIf(([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]=0) Or ([Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]<=[Limite_concedido]),0,DCount("[ID_STG_DATA]","T_REMESA_FINAL","[Exclusion_D]='Asegurado CESCE' AND [Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE] = " & [Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE] & " AND [Nominal] >= " & [Nominal] ))

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand how the DCount returns the correct data It effectively says *WHERE Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE= Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE*  ? 
If I create a query that replicates the DCount ? : *SELECT Count(T_REMESA_FINAL.ID_STG_DATA) AS CountResullt, T_REMESA_FINAL.ID_STG_DATA
FROM T_REMESA_FINAL
WHERE (((T_REMESA_FINAL.Exclusion_D)='Asegurado CESCE') AND ((T_REMESA_FINAL.Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE)=[T_REMESA_FINAL].[Sum_pagador_Asegurado_CESCE]) AND ((T_REMESA_FINAL.Nominal)>=[T_REMESA_FINAL].[Nominal]))
GROUP BY T_REMESA_FINAL.ID_STG_DATA;*

Comment: @Minty Thanks for your comment and suggestion. Looks like the query works nice on 2007 but puts a null value on ms-Access 365. We are gonna try reinstalling everything because it's a really strange situation

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I don't know why but uninstalling everything and reinstalling fixed the issue and now everything works perfectly. I'm not posting this as an aswer because it's not a real answer but just a solution.